# Angular chat client - 2 views with one controller

Tags: angularjs, chat

I build chat function in my web app and i am about to create chat functionality between logged clients. Here is my screen from application to show exactly what i want to solve

[Screen of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWtBP.jpg)

As you can see i got list of online users stored in scope in sidebar. Its created as partial view in my Asp.Net with .cshtml and i render content in "white box" using angular routing.

Problem is i use same controller twice and it creates new scope for each html so i got data in my sidebar, but in my content view i dont have any data. I am thinking about passing my data to rootscope, but i dont know if its good idea.

So my question is. Is there anything how i can clone my data from one controller to another or how i can solve this without changing functionality and if i can keep my views controlled with one controller.

Here is my PrivateChatController.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
app.controller('PrivateChatController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'SignalRService', '$location', 'PrivateChatService', PrivateChatController]);
function PrivateChatController($rootScope, $scope, SignalRService, $location, PrivateChatService) {


    //angular stuff
    $scope.online_users = [];

    $scope.isChatHidden = false;

    $scope.openPrivateChatWindow = function (index) {
      //  $scope.isChatHidden = true;
        angular.forEach($scope.online_users, function (value, key) {
            if (index == key) {
                $rootScope.currentPrivateChatUser = ({
                    UserName: value.UserName,
                    ConnectionId: value.connectionId,
                });

                $location.path("/details/" + value.UserName);
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.closePrivateChatWindow = function (index) {
        $scope.isChatHidden = false
    };


    //signalR stuff
    var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    chatHub.client.foo = function () { };
    registerClientMethods(chatHub);
    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); })
        .fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect!'); });

    function registerClientMethods(chatHub) {
        //user object

        chatHub.client.newOnlineUser = function (user) {
            var newUser = ({
                connectionId: user.ConnectionId,
                UserName: user.UserName
            });

            $scope.online_users.push(newUser);
            $scope.$apply();
        };

        //compare scope online users with server list of online users
        chatHub.client.getOnlineUsers = function (onlineUsers) {
            //loop through scope
            angular.forEach($scope.online_users, function (scopeValue, scopeKey) {
                //loop through received list of online users from server
                angular.forEach(onlineUsers, function (serverListValue, serverListKey) {
                    if (!(serverListValue.ConnectionId == scopeValue.connectionId)) {
                        var newUser = ({
                            connectionId: serverListValue.ConnectionId,
                            UserName: serverListValue.UserName
                        });
                        $scope.online_users.push(newUser);
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                })
            })
        };

        chatHub.client.onUserDisconnected = function (id, user) {
            var index = 0;
            //find out index of user
            angular.forEach($scope.online_users, function (value, key) {
                if (value.connectionId == id) {
                    index = key;
                }
            })

            $scope.online_users.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.$apply();
        };
    }};})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using services as a layer for data sharing. It should also contain chat related logic, in my opinion controllers should be as thin as possible.

Move `chatHub.client.getOnlineUsers` function to the service and create getter for `users`.

[Further read](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/passing-state-via-services)